# How to configure lint to ignore specific cases?

Tags: android, lint

Sometimes lint produces false warnins if field is operated via bunch of annotations. For a common example:

```
  @SerializedName("id") @Expose private Integer id;
```

field `id` is assigned only via gson.fromJson(). Such operation is invisible for lint, thus it throws warning `variable id is never assigned`
So I want to configure lint, in this particular case, to ignore checks if field is ever assigned, if it is annotated with `@SearializedName` (please dont suggest raw `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` which has to be set manualy for every field and will block checks, if field is ever used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gson serialises fields using reflection, which takes place at runtime. That UnusedAssignment inspection finds variables which meet any of the following criteria:

> - the variable never gets read after assignment
> - the value is always overwritten with another assignment before the next variable read
> - the variable initializer is redundant (for one of the above two reasons) - the variable is never used.

Your only option to get rid of warnings for this specific inspection is to suppress them, either by updating your lint.xml, or via `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`. If you really don't want to do either of those things, then it may be possible to write a [custom Lint inspection](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check) that ignores fields with a `@SerializedName` annotation.

The disadvantage of this approach is if you want to use `@SerializedName` in a class that isn't serialised by Gson, you will no longer get a warning if a variable is unused. It is also much more complicated than adding `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` to the top of your GSON model classes.